# Adding a radio button in PDFPCell iTextSharp

Tags: c#, radio-button, itext, radio-group, pdfptable

I am trying to add a radio button in itextsharp's pdfpcell. this is my code:

```
var rf1 = new RadioCheckField(writer, new Rectangle(10,10), "cellRadioBox", "Yes");
rf1.Checked = true;
rf1.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field = rf1.CheckField;

var radioEvents = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, rf1.GetRadioGroup(false,true));
radioCell.CellEvent = radioEvents;
table.AddCell(radioCell);
```

this creates a text block instead of a radio button. Maybe it is because of using `FieldPositioningEvents`. I don't know how to create a custom cell event for radio buttons. Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10);
var rf1 = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, LANGUAGES[i], "on");
rf1.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field = rf1.CheckField;
```

some references / examples can be found here [Buttons](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter08&ex=Buttons)
iText Books / Examples [Books|iText](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8)

Comment: thank you. But my main concern is about adding the radio to the pdfpcell and then to the table. Do i need to use `iTextSharp.text.pdf.events`?

Comment: why can't you create your own event check out the documentation links there are some examples.